# How to mark Jenkins build unstable if number of executed JUnit tests drops from previous build?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jenkins, continuous-integration

The Cobertura plugin has an option to mark a build unstable if coverage drops below a certain percentage (default is 0.0)

I was looking for a similar option to mark a build unstable if the number of executed JUnit tests suddenly drop, e.g. when a developer comments out a number of tests, or an error prevents the successful execution of remaining tests (this is very frequent with the Jasmine HTML runner).

Does such an option (or plugin) exist?